# command to record terminal does not work with bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I would like to use "script" command, I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
script & 
wait
echo "hello"
echo "hello2"
pid=$(pidof script | awk '{print $1}')
kill -9 $pid
```

I need the script command to capture the output, but after the command "script &" the output is :

```
         Script started, file is typescript             
         Script done, file is typescript
```

and script does not record nothing, any idea of why?

Comment: It is not recommended to run `script` in non-interactive shells. The inner shell of `script` is always interactive, and this could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: `script &` followed immediately by `wait` is equivalent to `script`.

Comment: Don't use `kill -9`. For well-behaved programs, `kill` is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
script <output-file> <commands>
```

**Example:**

```
script typescript bash -c 'echo "hello"; echo "hello2"'
Script started, output file is typescript
hello
hello2

Script done, output file is typescript
```

Then check output file created:

```
cat typescript
Script started on Sat Dec 19 01:54:04 2015
hello
hello2

Script done on Sat Dec 19 01:54:04 2015
```

Comment: You can also call a script e.g. **`script typescript bash -c ./something.sh`**

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can use the `script` command :

- Save only the outputs of your code (i.e. batch mode)

  ```
  $ script filename bash -c 'echo foo; echo bar'
  ```

  which will output

  ```
  Script started, file is filename
  foo
  bar
  Script done, file is filename
  ```
- Save all what is displayed on your terminal (i.e. interactive mode). To end the scripting, just type `exit` or hit Ctrl-D

  ```
  $ script filename
  Script started, file is filename
  $ echo foo
  foo
  $ echo bar
  bar
  $ exit
  exit
  Script done, file is filename
  ```

Note that the batch way is a hack on the interactive classical way of using `script`.

In your case, just forget about the `&` and `kill` stuff and hit Ctrl-D when you want the script to end.